# Confusion about java regex

Tags: java, regex

I was following  a tutorial [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/DisplaytheaddXXXListenermethodsofanySwingclass.htm), but I hit an obstacle: I don't know what this script does. I googled the expression, and I think it's called a regex. However, I still do not know what it is for.

```
  private static Pattern addListener = Pattern
  .compile("(add\\w+?Listener\\(.*?\\))");
```

Comment: What part did you not understand in that? The regex itself, or the method used?

Comment: [Or try hit 1 on Google](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refering the tutorial the regex would match all the `addListener` method definitions in `JTextField` class

---

`\w` would match a single `alphabet`,`number` or `_`

`+` is a quantifier which matches preceding pattern 1 to many times

So, `\w+` would match 1 to many words

---

`.` can match any character

`*` is a quantifier which matches preceding pattern 0 to many times

So, `.*` would match 0 to many characeters

`?` when used with `.*` makes it match lazily

For example,for input `xyzxyz`

`x.*z` regex would match `xyzxyz`

`x.*?z` regex would match `xyz`

---

`\\(.*?\\)` would match the round brackets with all the parameters inside

Answer (score 0):

it matches the following pattern:
"`(add`**word characters**`Listener(`**any characters**`))`
where words in bold are what is meant by `\\w` and `.*?` accordingly.

P.S. and you should better get familiar with [Pattern docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)